# How do I make windll.user32.SetWinEventHook work?

Tags: python, windows, events, hook, ctypes

I am trying to hook a focus change event using the following program in windows 11, python 3.11.

```
import win32con
import pythoncom
from ctypes import wintypes, windll, WINFUNCTYPE

# WinEventProc and GUITHREADINFO
WinEventProc = WINFUNCTYPE(
    None,
    wintypes.HANDLE,
    wintypes.DWORD,
    wintypes.HWND,
    wintypes.LONG,
    wintypes.LONG,
    wintypes.DWORD,
    wintypes.DWORD
)

# focus_changed function
def focus_changed(hWinEventHook, event, hwnd, idObject, idChild, dwEventThread, dwmsEventTime):
    print("Focus changed event detected")

# Main code
hook = windll.user32.SetWinEventHook(
    win32con.EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND,
    win32con.EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND,
    0,
    WinEventProc(focus_changed),
    0,
    0,
    win32con.WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT
)

if not hook:
    print(f"SetWinEventHook failed")

print("Script is running...")

while True:
    try:
        pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Exiting...")
        break

# Cleanup: Unhook events and release resources
windll.user32.UnhookWinEvent(hook)
```

I was expecting to see "Focus changed event detected" printed on the console when I start Notepad.

When I start the program above, it prints "Script is running...".

When I start notepad, the program above terminates silently without printing the focus changed event message or any other message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is using `WinEventProc(focus_changed)` as a paramter to `SetWinEventHook`.  This is an object whose reference count goes to zero and is freed immediately after the call.  From the [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) documentation:

> Note: Make sure you keep references to `CFUNCTYPE()` (*and `WINFUNCTYPE()`*) objects as long as they are used from C code. ctypes doesn’t, and if you don’t, they may be garbage collected, crashing your program when a callback is made.

One way to make a permanent reference is to simply decorate the callback function with the prototype.

Working code below.  Note also it is good practice to declare parameter types explicitly on `ctypes` functions for better type and error checking.  for example, `ctypes` assumes 32-bit integers for non-pointer parameters and all return values.  Handles are integers, but are 64-bit.  If the handle is large enough the value will be truncated unless the argument or return value is declared as a handle.

```py
import win32con
import pythoncom
import ctypes as ct
import ctypes.wintypes as w

WinEventProc = ct.WINFUNCTYPE(None, w.HANDLE, w.DWORD, w.HWND, w.LONG, w.LONG, w.DWORD, w.DWORD)

@WinEventProc  # Decorate the callback for a permanent reference
def focus_changed(hWinEventHook, event, hwnd, idObject, idChild, dwEventThread, dwmsEventTime):
    print('Focus changed event detected')

# Failure check helper for ctypes functinos
def fail_check(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise ct.WinError(ct.get_last_error())
    return result

# Good habit to explicitly declare arguments and result type of all functions
# used by ctypes for better type/error checking.
# "errcheck" suport will throw an exception with Win32 failure info if the function fails.
u32 = ct.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
u32.SetWinEventHook.argtypes = w.DWORD, w.DWORD, w.HMODULE, WinEventProc, w.DWORD, w.DWORD, w.DWORD
u32.SetWinEventHook.restype = w.HANDLE
u32.SetWinEventHook.errcheck = fail_check
u32.UnhookWinEvent.argtypes = w.HANDLE,
u32.UnhookWinEvent.restype = w.BOOL
u32.UnhookWinEvent.errcheck = fail_check

hook = u32.SetWinEventHook(
    win32con.EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, win32con.EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, 0,
    focus_changed, # changed from an object that immediately goes out of scope after hook call
    0, 0, win32con.WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT)

print('Script is running...')
try:
    while True:
        pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Exiting...')
u32.UnhookWinEvent(hook)
```